# Selecionar Linhas de um DataGrid e enviar para um Array

Tags: c#, array, wpf, datagrid

Tenho uma aplicação em WPF onde eu tenho um `DataGrid` com varias informações. Eu gostaria que o usuário pudesse escolher vários linhas e armazenar as informações da linha em um *array* (ou não) para eu enviar para uma outra tela e jogar em uma outra `DataGrid`.

Estou fazendo sem `CheckBox`, porém prefiro que a linha selecionada muda de cor...

Alguém conseguiria me dar um exemplo ou uma solução para esse problema?

Comment: Quando uma linha de um DataGrid é selecionado ele já muda de cor automaticamente, queres algo diferente disto?

Comment: Mas quando ele clica em outro, a cor volta ao normal.
Gostaria que ele ficasse com uma cor quando selecionasse cada linha do DataGrid

Comment: Na minha aplicação onde utilizo o DataGrid ao se clicar em outra linha com o botão Ctrl pressionado eles ficam destacados em azul.

Comment: Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde o usuário pode escolher varios items do DataGrid. Automaticamente ele devera selecionar varios items, sem a necessidade de segurar o Ctrl

Answer (score -1):

Faria uma coluna no grid do tipo hidden com o checkbox, e ao selecionar, adicionaria em uma lista na sua controller. Talvez esse link possa lhe ajudar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496751/wpf-datagrid-programmatic-multiple-row-selection